Purpose of trace pattern on RF PCB
When looking at a front-end PCB in 7 GHz spectrum analyzer I did see a multitude of trace patterns that I did not understand the purpose of. For example, the ones seen in the image below. Can anyone help explain these?
My only guess would be that it is to reduce standing waves.
Out of curiosity, is there an online resource that at least briefly touches some common patterns utilised in RF applications?


It's called distributed-element circuits. They are used in microwave frequencies, where the wavelength is comparable to the dimensions of the circuit - when propagation speed matters, when "parasitic" reactive elements are significant instead of parasitic The wikipedia article on distributed-element circuits gives an introduction, and examples of typical components.
Examples of circuits, snipped from wiki:

Butterfly stub filter

Microstrip band-pass hairpin filter (left), followed by a low-pass stub filter
