This PCB from doppler radar from car to detect blind angles how are these traces made?
This PCB from Doppler radar from a car to detect blind angles
My  question
How were these traces made?
From where it can learn to design a kind of board?
What essential do I need to learn?
Any course or book name?


Relevant link 1: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94037/can-anyone-explain-this-high-frequency-alien-voodoo-black-magic

Relevant link 2: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/721944/purpose-of-trace-pattern-on-rf-pcb

A designer would need to learn electromagnetic field theory. EE departments would offer such courses. Ramo Whinnery and VanDuzer is a classic book but there are many more. Facility in using electromagnetic field modeling software would also be required.


How were these traces made?

That is a printed circuit board. Some substrate (here, some RF ceramic) got coated with copper, then a photosensitive lacquer was applied.
Then, the lacquer was exposed with an (potentially inverse) image of the shape these traces should take, "developed", and finally, the copper got etched away.
Finally, a protective layer of gold has been plated onto the copper.

From where it can learn to design a kind of board?

University! You can study electrical engineering. And within that field of study, you can specialize in high-frequency electronics (later on, typically), and within that, in circuit board design.

What essential do I need to learn?

Roughly the following lectures would have been what you would have taken at my university. Each bullet point (including the "nested" points) is roughly equivalent to a lecture including a hall exercise, taking place weekly, for all 13 lecture weeks of an academic half-year:

Basics of linear networks

requires basics in complex/multivariate calculus


Transmission line theory

requires all the above
requires basics in electromagnetics & waves

requires basics in analysis / calculus
requires basics in physics




microwave engineering

requires all the above
requires basics in signals and systems


design of analog circuitry

requires basics of electrical engineering
requires basics of semiconductor circuits



Quite likely you'd probably also want to hear lectures on

communications technology

requires basics in signals and systems
requires basics in probability theory


antenna and multi-antenna systems

requires microwave engineering


radar systems

requires microwave engineering


testing and design for microwave devices

requires microwave engineering
typically comes with a lab course




Any course or book name?

I'd honestly recommend you talk to someone at a university that you might want to attend. You can sketch your way there, which courses you can take in which order and so on. Books are hard to recommend: If I just listed all the recommendable books from the math basics to the engineering practices, you wouldn't be helped that much, because it's much harder to learn this all (this is a 2 to 4 year effort!) by books alone, instead of in the academic context of a series of lectures, where professors have invested the time into teaching you things with how important they will be later on.

Thanks very very helpful
